# Migrating DHCP To new server with same IP

Tags: dhcp

I have DHCP being used across VLANs, so I want to keep the same IP address on my new DHCP Server. I have found many guides that make it look very easy to export/import dhcp records using powershell, so that part is straightforward, but what I'm not finding is much detail about how to reconcile moving to a new server with the same IP.

What are the cutover steps?  Do I import DHCP records on the new server, then change its IP?  I assume the hostname does not need to be the same, or would it be easier if it was?  Then How do I deauthorize the old server if I've already changed it to an alternate IP?  Any help appreciated.

Also, for reference, I would be migrating from Server 2012R2 to Server 2022.

Comment: Why do you want to keep the same IP address?

Comment: I've actually already resolved this, but the server hands out IP's over multiple VLANs so changing the IP would have meant changing a bunch of helper IP's as well.  As it is, I exported the leases from Server 1, imported to server 2.  Changed IP on server 1 to an alternate, changed IP on server 2 to server 1's former IP.  Then I installed the DHCP role, authorized it on the domain, and imported the stuff I had exported from server 1.  That was pretty much it.